# What should I set for OpenIdConnectOptions.SignOutScheme?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, identityserver4, identity, claims-based-identity

I'm using .NET 6 and Identity Server 4.

What should I set for `OpenIdConnectOptions.SignOutScheme`?

This is what I have in `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
       .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenIdConnect", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme; // "idsrv.external"
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme; // "idsrv"
            options.Authority = "https://saas.oktapreview.com";
            options.ClientId = "someId";
            options.ClientSecret = "someSecret";
            options.ResponseType = "code";
            options.Events = new MriOpenIdConnectEvents();
       }
```

I've chosen `IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme` purely because it has "signout" in the name.

But can you use the same value as for `SignInScheme`?

How does this value affect OIDC?

Comment: I'd love to know what this does and what values are acceptable also. The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.signoutscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is useless

Comment: @StuartKemp this might help:
https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Support/issues/893